# Sum of amounts of a table without union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have asked a question by an interviwer that how can i achieve a grand total of the column without using any union all.could any help me for this.i have tried few cases but they didn't worked.any help would be appreciated.

Sample Table:

```
select * into #tab from (

    select 1 as id,10 amount
    union all
    select 2,20
    union all
    select 3,40 
    )as a
    select * from #tab
```

From below query i got the result but here im not supposed to use union all

```
 select  convert(varchar(250),id) as Ids ,amount from #tab
   union all
  select 'Total' as Total,Sum(Amount)as Final_Amount from #tab
```

My required output:

```
    Ids amount
    1   10
    2   20
    3   40
  Total 70
```

Comment: What is input and what is expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by ROLLUP

```
select  case when GROUPING(id) = 1 then 'Total' else convert(varchar(250),id) end as Ids 
        ,sum(amount)    as  amount
from #tab
group by id WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with `grouping sets`:

```
select CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 'Total' ELSE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) END AS id, sum(amount) 
from #tab 
group by grouping sets(id, ())
```

Answer (score 1):

i too tried ROLLUP

```
Select isnull(id,'Total') id,amount from    
    (
    select distinct cast(id as varchar)id,sum(amount) amount
     from #tab
    group by id with rollup
    )t4
    order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

This one..Insert the total to itself (#tab).

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tab') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #tab
    END

     /*============
       Sample table: 
      =============*/

    SELECT  *
    INTO    #tab
    FROM    ( SELECT    1 AS id ,
                        10 amount
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    2 ,
                        20
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    3 ,
                        40
            ) AS a

           /*=== END ==*/


            INSERT  INTO #tab
                    SELECT  0 id ,
                            SUM(amount) amount
                    FROM    #tab

            SELECT  CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN 'TOTAL'
                         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(250), id)
                    END id ,
                    amount
            FROM    #tab
```

Result:

```
    id     amount
    ----   ----------
    1      10
    2      20
    3      40
    TOTAL  70

    (4 row(s) affected)
```